# VS 2015 gitignore and setting files to untracked

Tags: git, gitignore, visual-studio-2015

Started an asp.net 5 mvc project using Git with Team Project. Did not notice that wwwroot was included. Have now checked in various files but would like that root directory totally ignored. Does not seem possible to do this in the Team Explorer window.

Also, when using settings-repositories and changing .gitignore, I have tried to exclude this folder. But that does not seem to do the trick.
I see the new project.json file has an exclude section with wwwroot in it.

Since I cannot seem to unlink these files/folders from Git, I will probably delete them all for now and see what happens when they are restored.
...
Yes, that did the trick. But any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking this as an answer even though it may not be the idiomatic Git way of doing things. For VS though, we have to work around the vagaries of the Team Explorer.